# Fetching a jsdom window variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I'm trying to access a variable inside a jsom instance, from outside:

Here's an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
  <script>
    window.foo = "hello world";
  </script>
</head>
  ....
</html>
```

And then trying to access the *foo* variable from "outside" jsdom:

```
let dom = new JSDOM(...);
dom.window.onload = () => { console.log(dom.window.foo); }; // prints undefined
```

This issue seems to describe an [identical GitHub issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2287) where the author solved it by removing the *resources* option. However, I cannot do that because I need external scripts to run.

Is there any way I can call a function or access some variable that exists within a jsdom instance, with *resources* set to *usable*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) which says:

> jsdom's most powerful ability is that it can execute scripts inside the jsdom. … this is also highly dangerous … the ability to execute scripts embedded in the HTML is disabled by default … To enable executing scripts inside the page, you can use the `runScripts: "dangerously"` option

Thus:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const dom = new JSDOM(`<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
  <script>
    window.foo = "hello world";
  </script>
</head>
  ....
</html>
`, { runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable" });

dom.window.onload = () => { console.log(dom.window.foo); };
```

Comment: I already have that option. It doesn't affect being able to access the window variables from outside the dom. It only affects being able to run scripts inside the dom, which is unrelated. Here's what I have: let dom = new JSDOM(html, { url: "https://localhost:5001/" + path, contentType: "text/html", includeNodeLocations: true, storageQuota: 10000000, runScripts: "dangerously", resources: new jsdom.ResourceLoader({ strictSSL: false })}).

Comment: @HelloWorld — The script in this answer runs and outputs "hello world". If I change the options to match the ones in your comment then … the script in this answer still runs and outputs "hello world". So this answer solves everything you asked about in this question.

Comment: @HelloWorld — Probably your real problem is related to how the JS embedded in the HTML document actually works, but you simplified it so much that you removed the problem from it. This is why you need to provide a [mcve] **and test it demonstrates the problem**  instead of just some snippets of code.

Comment: I am beginning to think you are correct sir! ;) I have detected some other things here... My question is incorrect. I'll upvote your answer and delete my question :)